# Nginx rewrite rule not working

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Can someone help me convert this rule?

I have over 50 rules, but I can not make this rule work:

```
#APACHE
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?cmm=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The question needs much more information about the setup before there can be good answers.

Answer (score 3):

nginx always requires the leading slash in the URI part of the rewrite, while Apache doesn't want it.

Without seeing the complete configuration, this is just a guess what the problem might be.

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?cmm=$1&page=$2 last;
```